# How to enable experimental reverse port forwarding in chrome?

Tags: adb, nexus-4, chrome-for-android, macos

> Commonly you have a web server running on your local development
>   machine, and you want to connect to that site from your device. If the
>   mobile device and the development machine are on the same network,
>   this is straightforward. But this may be difficult in some cases, like
>   on a restricted corporate network.

This is what I ran into at work.I have been trying to get my web application that runs on my my localhost to be accessible on my mobile device.

- Desktop OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Desktop Chrome: Version 30.0.1599.69
- Mobile OS: Android 4.3 (Nexus4)
- Mobile Chrome: Version 30.0.1599.82

I found an [article](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=ru#reverse-port-forwarding) about chrome experimental features that was explaining you how to enable **reverse port forwarding** in chrome. I have been following the article until it said to tick the checkbox for "Enable reverse port forwarding" in "developer tools > settings > experiments". **I found the tick list but could not find that option.** Does anyone know how I can enable this reverse port forwarding?

Comment: When you say "localhost", do you mean the device's localhost (itself) or do you just mean you're running a webserver on your desktop? Or am I missing something?

Comment: In this case I mean localhost on the desktop.

Comment: Are you unable to configure the server software and any applicable firewalls? If configured properly, you should be able to view the page without anything special, assuming the phone and desktop are on the same LAN. If there's some special reason you ned reverse port forwarding, it would probably help to give added details about your special case.

Comment: Read the question again and noticed something I missed before: You kinda already answered my question (Sorry!). Just to confirm: Is this a case where (like in the article you linked) you're on a restricted network that makes the normal method impractical?

Comment: I'm looking at my Chrome (Arch Linux) and it doesn't have "Enable reverse port forwarding". However, it does have "Enable port forwarding" in exactly the same position (between "toolbar customization" and "console as overlay"). Perhaps it got renamed? Did you see/try that option?

Comment: Figured it out. Yes @dotVezz it was just a rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that what I was looking for was right in front of me. The **option** "Reverse port forwarding" from the [article](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=ru#reverse-port-forwarding) was **renamed** to "port forwarding" .